# componentDidUpdate inner working confuses me

Tags: reactjs

One of my React component receive a Array of JSON. And the component contain a componentDidUpdate. I know this function run right before rendering, and I get to see the nextProps and nextState, so I can compare them with the current. However the inner working confuses me

---

Here are the steps of my program:

1. parent Component pass newly updated list to this component
2. This component run componentDidUpdate:

   - Compare old list to this new updated list. Find the newly added item, push it into this component's state (an array call `differenceList`)
3. this component render according to the `differenceList`

---

Following is my console.log that I've placed all over.

//after I trigger a update of the list

1. Entering ComponentWillUpdate
2. Found the unique item: "1336" and next line of code push it into array
3. Should have just pushed it into array with `self.setState({differenceList: self.state.differenceList.concat(item.id)});`
4. reached end of ComponentWillUpdate, this.state.differenceList is: [] //what??
5. Entering rendering function, this.state.differenceList is: []
6. Entering ComponentWillUpdate  //why again?
7. end of ComponentWillUpdate, this.state.differenceList is: []
8. Entering rendering function, this.state.differenceList is: ["1336"]

why is `#4` showing empty??

at `#6` why did it enter componentWillUpdate again? is it because I updated the state inside componentWillUpdate? but if so why is `#5` showing empty state `#8` Now after entering render function again, it suddenly show the changed state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is because `setState` is asynchronous.

1. `<Parent/>` tries to render `<Child list={[1, 2, 1336]}/>` (Batch 0)

   - `willUpdate()` gets called with `nextProps = {list: [1, 2, 1336]}`
   - `self.setState({differenceList: self.state.differenceList.concat(['1336'])}) // This code is asynchronous, creating Batch 1`
   - End of `willUpdate()`, this.state is still the same
   - `render()`
2. Treating Batch 1 (your `setState()` call)

   - `willUpdate()` with `nextState = { ... differenceList: ['1336'] }`
   - `this.state` still not updated
   - End of `willUpdate()`
   - `render()` with new state

I'm not sure I'm being very clear, I'm a bit tired.
Anyways, [you should not be using `this.setState` in `componentWillUpdate()`.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate)
Try using [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) for your purposes.

Comment: I read that site a couple times, cant believe I missed the important notes. Thanks a lot! The asynchronous make sense to me thanks!